# Python convert list of one element into string with bracket

Tags: python

How to convert python list containing one element to string with bracket?
For more than one element, its easy for me to just just use `tuple(list['a','b'])` which returns as tuple `('a','b')` but if element is one, it returns as `('a',)` but rather I want to return `('a')`
sample:

```
mylist = ["a", " b"]
print tuple([s.strip() for s in mylist])
>> ('a', 'b')

mylist = ["a"]
print tuple([s.strip() for s in mylist])
>> ('a', ) #rather I want to return ('a')
```

Comment: `('a')` is `'a'` - is that what you want? Single element tuple contains comma to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: `('a')` - with bracket

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Avoid relying on default `__repr__()` method, to format strings, they might change.

Be explicit about your intent instead

```
 print "('" + "', '".join(mylist) + "')"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> ('a') == 'a'
True
```

If you're not going to use a single element tuple, then the parenthesis are only grouping parenthesis (not a container), and they won't *stick* like you want them to, except you include them as part of the string with `a` or define a custom print function.

With the custom print function, you get to keep the conversion from list to tuple (i.e. `t = tuple(mylist)`) as is and also use the single element tuple as is:

```
def tuple_print(t):
    print(str(t).replace(',', '') if len(t) == 1 else t)
```

**Trials**:

```
>>> def tuple_print(t):
...      print(str(t).replace(',', '') if len(t) == 1 else t)
...
>>> mylist = ["a"]
>>> t = tuple(mylist)
>>> t
('a',)
>>> tuple_print(t)
('a')
>>> t = ('a', 'b')
>>> tuple_print(t)
('a', 'b')
```