# saving file with format

Tags: python, writefile

Hi guys I am trying to save my file in python...
I dont know how to do it.. It came out the save file to be like this :
506882122734561843241851186242872

What I am trying to do is
["50688", "212273", "4561843", "241851", "18624", "2872"]

```
with open("output_data.txt", "w") as out_file:
    for user in users:
        out_string = ""
        out_string += str(user)
        out_file.write(out_string)
```

Comment: It looks you want to save JSON file. Is that the case?

Comment: What was `user` before you wrote it to the file, and how was it produced? In order to help you, we need a [mre] including the input data...

Comment: If that's really a JSON, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309269/how-do-i-write-json-data-to-a-file

Comment: If you're not trying to save it into a JSON file, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38186365/python-convert-list-of-one-element-into-string-with-bracket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop you're using is stitching together each of the elements in your `users` list so you end up with one long string in `out_string`. You probably introduced this loop after you got an error message when trying to save the list straight to a file.

Instead, and as suggested in the comments, you could save the data as JSON:

```py
import json

users = ["50688", "212273", "4561843", "241851", "18624", "2872"]

with open("output_data.txt", "w") as out_file:
    out_file.write(json.dumps(users))
```

`output_data.txt` will then contain:

```json
["50688", "212273", "4561843", "241851", "18624", "2872"]
```

Note: this assumes that your original list is a list of strings, not integers (it wasn't clear from your question).

Comment: just `json.dump(users, out_file)` is enough. The question is whether OP really want JSON and why not using correct file extension.

Comment: that's true, I was trying to include as much of their original code as possible in case it was less of a leap

Answer (score 0):

You are saving `user` variables without any delimiters.

You can try to use `str.join` to add commas like

```py
users = ["0", "1", "2"]
users = ",".join(users)
print(users)  # should print '0,1,2'
```

You can also use `repr` to print string with quotes.

```py
user = "3"
print(repr(user))  # should print '"3"'
```

Now you can combine both methods

```py
with open("output_data.txt", "w") as file:
    users = map(repr, users)
    users = ", ".join(users)
    users = "[" + users + "]"
    file.write(users)
```

Comment: If OP really wants JSON there is proper way to do it, not construct JSON yourself.